# Creating Plots in a Loop (R)

Tags: r, loops

I wrote this loop in R that generates a random data set and then makes a plot for this random data set:

```
    library(ggplot2)

results = list()

for (i in 1:100)

{

my_data_i = data.frame(var_1 = rnorm(100,10,10), var_2 = rnorm(100,10,10))

plot_i = ggplot(my_data_i, aes(x=var_1, y=var_2)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(paste0("graph", i))

results[[i]] = plot_i

}
```

Can someone please show me how to extract each individual plot from this list and create a file in the global environment : plot_1, plot_2... plot_100?

Thank you!

Comment: It is better not to create objects in the global env.  instead keep it in a list and extract as `results[[1]]`, `results[[2]]` etc

Comment: Note that if `i` is used to subset the data,  `ggplot` will not work as expected in a `for` loop. In your example that is not a problem, since you create the data in the loop, but if you do something like `aes(x = iris[, i])` `i` is not evaluated until when you print the plot and then all plots look the same. Just mentioning this in case your real problem is differs from your example here. You can avoid this problem by using `lapply` or `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we mentioned in the comments, it is better not to create 100 objects in the global env, instead store it in a `list`.  This can be done either with a `for` loop (as showed in the OP's code, but create a NULL list of required length and do the assign)

```
results <- vector('list', 100)
for (i in seq_along(results)

{

my_data_i <- data.frame(var_1 = rnorm(100,10,10), var_2 = rnorm(100,10,10))

plot_i <- ggplot(my_data_i, aes(x=var_1, y=var_2)) +
            geom_point() + 
             ggtitle(paste0("graph", i))

results[[i]] = plot_i

}
names(results) <- paste0('plot_', seq_along(results))
```

and then extract with either `$` or `[[`

```
results[['plot_1']]
results$plot_1
```

---

Another option without preassigning is to use `lapply`

```
results2 <- lapply(1:100, function(i) {
          my_data_i <- data.frame(var_1 = rnorm(100,10,10), var_2 = rnorm(100,10,10))

 ggplot(my_data_i, aes(x=var_1, y=var_2)) +
            geom_point() + 
             ggtitle(paste0("graph", i))
   })
names(results2) <- paste0("plot_", seq_along(results2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I just figured this out?

```
list2env(setNames(results,paste0("plot",seq(results))),envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Is this correct?